# How to test the environment in TDD?

Tags: language-agnostic, tdd

As I continue to learn and apply TDD I reach some points where I don't know how I could test before writing code (as I should).
It's with anything that's outside my application such as testing that:

- Files have changed (e.g. renamed).
- A program has launched / terminated / moved etc.

How do I test these kind of things?

*EDIT:*
I'd like to focus on the first example, since I'm working on an application that actually requires those tests. How can I test the changing of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any test which depends on the environment is not a unit test - it's an integration test. TDD does not apply to these.

You can, of course, create integration tests, and you can, or course, write those tests before you write the code that they test.

Comment: Could you give me a little more? the term integration test is new to me. I did look it up but I don't see how it's appropriate for my situation (given that I have very little control on the filesystem/Windows processes modules).

Comment: A unit test tests a small unit of functionality, independent of anything that unit depends on. An integration test tests how two or more components work together. For instance, how does your data access code work with the database.

Comment: Okay, so how do you both make sure you can write to the database, and also not alter it? This is my exact situations. I learned in "TDD by example" that I even can't just write that function, or even calling it out of the box, since I need to test it first. So in a simple example (a file): how can I create a new file? what would be the test for that?

Comment: You _can_ write tests like that, but you usually don't need to. That's not the sort of thing that breaks and also needs to be automated. Simple manual testing will show whether your connection strings are correct. You would not test whether you can create a file. You would test whether you can create the correct contents, possibly by passing a `TextWriter` to the method that writes. In the test, you would use a `StringWriter`, and test that the contents were correct. No need to play with the file system.

Comment: Makes sense. So in situations like these I should simply write the function without testing first? I wasn't aware that these kind of exceptions exist.

Comment: No, you write the functional to be testable. You write the function as accepting a `TextWriter`, instead of a file path.

Comment: Yes, I meant just the method that will save the file (not the contents). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing integration tests. Different from unit tests, which test isolated pieces of logic, integration tests function to make sure all of the pieces can properly communicate with each other.

Your integration test will reference property files, start up & shut down your service, and generally ensure none of your moving parts have been broken.

Sometimes, it is wise to [mock](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) the components. After all, you're not really testing the components, but the environment in which they operate.

Comment: "After all, you're not really testing the components" - That's exactly where my confusion lies. If I need to make a system call for an actual change of file, how do I test that? I can't just call it, because I must test it first. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: You don't test the system call. It's not broken. Test your code that calls the system call. You need a new mindset.